# Text overflowing off screen in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

[image: RecyclerView Text Truncation]

As you can see I am experiencing the text within `RecyclerView` wrapping but some of it is off screen (highlighted parts are the matching parts)

[image: Full text]

I loaded fragment_news which contains the `RecyclerView` into the `FrameLayout` in activity_main, and news_list_item defines the items in the `RecyclerView`. I think I have messed up some properties somewhere but I am not sure which one(s).

Here is the xml code I am using:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_news.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".news.NewsFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/news_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

news_list_item.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_item_padding_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_item_padding_horizontal"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_item_padding_horizontal"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_item_padding_vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/news_item_image"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/news_item_headline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/news_item_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You probably have to change news_list_item.xml 
Try adding some padding/margin it may solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated (ConstraintLayout 1.1.+)

Use 
    `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` with width set to `wrap_content`
in your TextView.
Also set the width to 0dp in your TextView

#### Previously (deprecated):

`app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` with width set to `0dp`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_item_image"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_message_bubble"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sodales accumsan tortor at bibendum." />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: As well as using your changes I had to add `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"` and then it worked

Comment: Dis you add that attribute to the TextView?